# Artifactory PostgreSQL HikariCP errors

Tags: postgresql, artifactory, hikaricp

I recently moved our Artifactory database to a newly build Postgres HA cluster.

Artifactory itself is running in a docker container while the Postgres cluster runs on own virtual servers building a HA cluster through Patroni.

While connecting and setting it up worked, there are now errors in the log about slow queries and HikariCP failing to validate the connection:

> 2022-05-23T06:16:43.595Z [jfac ] [WARN ] [d3a436283f12bf94] [c.z.h.p.PoolBase:184          ] [jf-access-task8     ] - HikariCP Main - Failed to validate connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@f32a6c4 (This connection has been closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.

> 2022-05-23T06:17:04.729Z [jfac ] [WARN ] [                ] [c.z.h.p.PoolBase:184          ] [efault-executor-4398] - HikariCP Main - Failed to validate connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@3fb91ee6 (This connection has been closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.

> 2022-05-23T06:17:36.996Z [jfac ] [WARN ] [265a1aa154894c1b] [c.z.h.p.PoolBase:184          ] [7.0.0.1-8040-exec-10] - HikariCP Main - Failed to validate connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@1b08eca5 (This connection has been closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.

> 2022-05-23T06:17:38.319Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [                ] [database_bearer.go:368        ] [main                ] - Slow statement detected (6.794897251s) - UPDATE md_servers SET last_heartbeat = $1 WHERE id = $2 [database]

> 2022-05-23T06:17:38.569Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [                ] [database_bearer.go:368        ] [main                ] - Slow query detected (6.683101054s) - SELECT task_key, execution_interval_millis, progress, modified, task_start_key, task_end_key, depends_on FROM md_tasks [database] [workerNumber][1]

These also lead to the result that when I import the backup of the old database, it will fail at some random points and have artifacts missing in the end.

I tried to change the maxLifetime value for Hiakri but I couldn't find out where.
The "/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory" directory in the container is mapped to a static folder on the host so I tried setting it in the system.yaml but with no effect.

Right now my system.yaml looks like this:

```
shared:
    database:
        type: postgresql
        driver: org.postgresql.Driver
        url: jdbc:postgresql://postgreshost/artifactory
        username: artifactory
        password: myPassword
```

Where can I then change the value for maxLifetime or is it possible that the errors come from something different?

**EDIT**:

The Postgres log looks like this:

```
2022-05-23 12:56:46.413 CEST [604373] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2022-05-23 12:56:46.413 CEST [604373] LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction
2022-05-23 13:14:12.083 CEST [617283] ERROR:  deadlock detected
2022-05-23 13:14:12.083 CEST [617283] DETAIL:  Process 617283 waits for ShareLock on transaction 3362529; blocked by process 617510.
        Process 617510 waits for ShareLock on transaction 3362515; blocked by process 617283.
        Process 617283: UPDATE access_topology SET state = $1, last_updated = $2 WHERE endpoint_id = $3
        Process 617510: UPDATE access_topology SET state = $1, last_updated = $2 WHERE endpoint_id = $3
2022-05-23 13:14:12.083 CEST [617283] HINT:  See server log for query details.
2022-05-23 13:14:12.083 CEST [617283] CONTEXT:  while updating tuple (0,19) in relation "access_topology"
2022-05-23 13:14:12.083 CEST [617283] STATEMENT:  UPDATE access_topology SET state = $1, last_updated = $2 WHERE endpoint_id = $3
2022-05-23 13:14:12.083 CEST [617510] LOG:  duration: 2591.626 ms  execute <unnamed>: UPDATE access_topology SET state = $1, last_updated = $2 WHERE endpoint_id = $3
2022-05-23 13:14:12.083 CEST [617510] DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = 'HEALTHY', $2 = '1653304449485', $3 = '2'
2022-05-23 13:24:54.601 CEST [602250] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2022-05-23 13:26:03.849 CEST [619028] WARNING:  there is no transaction in progress
2022-05-23 13:26:04.021 CEST [615736] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2022-05-23 13:26:04.021 CEST [615736] LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction
2022-05-23 13:46:49.625 CEST [612081] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2022-05-23 13:54:01.641 CEST [622155] WARNING:  there is no transaction in progress
2022-05-23 13:54:01.821 CEST [619028] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2022-05-23 13:54:01.821 CEST [619028] LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction
2022-05-23 14:03:18.089 CEST [623174] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2022-05-23 14:08:11.485 CEST [622155] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2022-05-23 14:12:51.144 CEST [618894] LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction
2022-05-23 14:33:30.014 CEST [626629] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2022-05-23 14:58:48.349 CEST [606834] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2022-05-23 15:32:18.237 CEST [629334] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2022-05-23 15:35:24.877 CEST [623774] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2022-05-23 15:52:01.765 CEST [632939] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2022-05-23 15:52:01.765 CEST [632939] LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction
2022-05-23 15:55:18.621 CEST [609860] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2022-05-23 16:09:03.689 CEST [620914] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2022-05-23 16:09:03.689 CEST [620914] LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction
2022-05-23 16:13:49.429 CEST [636884] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2022-05-23 16:29:46.716 CEST [605671] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2022-05-23 16:31:04.776 CEST [639239] WARNING:  there is no transaction in progress
2022-05-23 16:31:04.949 CEST [621365] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2022-05-23 16:31:04.949 CEST [621365] LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction
2022-05-23 17:03:12.241 CEST [637393] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2022-05-23 17:38:06.594 CEST [610944] LOG:  could not send data to client: Connection reset by peer
2022-05-23 17:38:06.594 CEST [610944] STATEMENT:  select itemid,functionid,name,parameter,triggerid from functions
2022-05-23 17:38:06.594 CEST [610944] FATAL:  connection to client lost
2022-05-23 17:38:06.594 CEST [610944] STATEMENT:  select itemid,functionid,name,parameter,triggerid from functions
2022-05-23 17:38:54.605 CEST [639239] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2022-05-23 17:38:54.605 CEST [639239] LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction
2022-05-23 18:02:18.184 CEST [648559] LOG:  duration: 5929.036 ms  execute <unnamed>: DELETE FROM archive_names WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM indexed_archives_entries i WHERE i.entry_name_id = name_id)
2022-05-23 19:30:02.765 CEST [658076] WARNING:  there is no transaction in progress
2022-05-23 19:30:02.933 CEST [635061] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2022-05-23 19:30:02.933 CEST [635061] LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction
2022-05-23 19:30:02.937 CEST [633277] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2022-05-23 19:30:02.937 CEST [633277] LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction
2022-05-23 19:40:56.365 CEST [659235] WARNING:  there is no transaction in progress
2022-05-23 19:40:56.529 CEST [639099] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2022-05-23 19:40:56.529 CEST [639099] LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction
2022-05-23 19:52:11.589 CEST [590926] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2022-05-23 19:52:28.782 CEST [653019] LOG:  could not send data to client: Connection reset by peer
2022-05-23 19:52:28.782 CEST [653019] STATEMENT:  select triggerid,description,expression,error,priority,type,value,state,lastchange,status,recovery_mode,recovery_expression,correlation_mode,correlation_tag,opdata,event_name,null,null,n>2022-05-23 19:52:28.782 CEST [653019] FATAL:  connection to client lost
2022-05-23 19:52:28.782 CEST [653019] STATEMENT:  select triggerid,description,expression,error,priority,type,value,state,lastchange,status,recovery_mode,recovery_expression,correlation_mode,correlation_tag,opdata,event_name,null,null,n>2022-05-23 19:53:45.017 CEST [2301] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2022-05-23 20:02:31.205 CEST [661487] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2022-05-23 20:21:44.867 CEST [663487] LOG:  duration: 1576.960 ms  execute <unnamed>: UPDATE access_topology SET state = $1, last_updated = $2 WHERE endpoint_id = $3
2022-05-23 20:21:44.867 CEST [663487] DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = 'HEALTHY', $2 = '1653330103289', $3 = '9002'
2022-05-23 20:40:16.014 CEST [665490] WARNING:  there is no transaction in progress
2022-05-23 20:40:16.177 CEST [658077] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2022-05-23 20:40:16.177 CEST [658077] LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction
2022-05-23 20:50:51.189 CEST [666502] LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction
2022-05-23 20:55:00.297 CEST [666590] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2022-05-23 21:17:08.552 CEST [669403] WARNING:  there is no transaction in progress
2022-05-23 21:17:08.721 CEST [658076] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2022-05-23 21:17:08.721 CEST [658076] LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction
2022-05-23 21:30:06.624 CEST [665490] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2022-05-23 21:46:20.992 CEST [672459] WARNING:  there is no transaction in progress
2022-05-23 21:46:21.161 CEST [669403] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2022-05-23 21:46:21.161 CEST [669403] LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction
2022-05-23 22:25:21.813 CEST [610953] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2022-05-23 23:01:26.281 CEST [680388] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2022-05-23 23:29:56.756 CEST [683342] LOG:  duration: 1211.342 ms  execute <unnamed>: UPDATE access_topology SET state = $1, last_updated = $2 WHERE endpoint_id = $3
2022-05-23 23:29:56.756 CEST [683342] DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = 'HEALTHY', $2 = '1653341395543', $3 = '9002'
```

Comment: None of those are errors, just warnings and info.  Are there actual errors as well?  What do you see in the PostgreSQL log file?

Comment: Sorry I know, but as they are the only ting Artifactory is showing and they are repeating constantly they seemed to be the problem for me.